# Do inconsistent premises in an argument hurt a person's case while they try to defend something they believe in?

Tags: fallacies, argumentation, ontological-argument

Do inconsistent premises in an argument hurt a person's case while they try to defend something they believe in because their statements contradict each other?

Comment: Yes. If people believe contradictory things at least one of them must be wrong, and that does not bode well for their system of beliefs as a whole.

Answer (score 3):

If the premises are supposed to be taken for granted, and they are contradictory, then anything at all can be logically shown to follow from them (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion).  So this would clearly make the argument suspect.